# Unsorted dates after sorting in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, date

Sometimes, even though I sort the column dates from early to late,
some dates remain unsorted. 
I fix it by rewriting the dates manually, but this is inefficient.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like Excel is treating your G column as numerically formatted, rather than date formatted. Notice how each date is lined up in order as if it were a single large number?

Select your G column, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd> to open the format window, and select the appropriate date format.

Comment: @Mikey-t-k When "/" is there twice, how can it be numerically formatted?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Excel understands that those values are dates? 
Is your system set up to understand `dd/mm/yyyy` formatting? 
If you put `=G42+1` into `Q42`,
does it show you a date one day after the date in `G42`? 
Can you change the date formatting to something like `dd mmm yyyy`
(in which the month *name* is spelled out)? 
If you add an `17/08/2017`entry to your list,
does it sort before all the 2018 dates,
or does it group with the other `17/08` dates?

It looks like Excel is treating those values as text strings
and sorting by the first few characters
(just as "agreed" sorts between "adroit" and "bakery").

Some parts of the world (most(?) of the English-speaking parts of the world?)
use `mm/dd/yyyy`, and if you're in one of those parts of the world
(or Excel thinks you are) it will interpret `12/08/2018` as December 8, 2018,
and it will interpret `17/08/2018` as a string,
because it doesn't make sense as a `mm/dd/yyyy` date.